# Find recurrence relation and general solution

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, combinations

I need help finding recurrence relation.

We will glue a decorative tile with a size of 1 × n squares. We have available

- tiles of 4 colors with size 1x1 square
- tiles of 5 colors with size 1x2 square

How much combinations is there to make decorative tile of size 1 x n squares? And what's the recurrence relation. I don't even know how to start solving this. Can you solve it or help me?

Answer (score 1):

Denoting  $u_n$ the number of possibilities, you have $u_0=1$, and $u_1=4$.

Then the first tile can be a $1x1$ square, with four possibilities, and then you pave the $n-1$ other squares, or it can be a $1x2$ block, with five possibilities, and then you pave the $n-2$ other squares, and all solutions are distinct.

To say it shorty, for $n \ge 2$, $u_n = 4u_{n-1}+5u_{n-2}$.

The roots of the characteristic polynomial $X^2-4X-5$ are $5$ and $-1$ so $u_n = \alpha 5^n + \beta (-1)^n$. Using $u_0=1$ and $u_1=4$, we get $\alpha=\frac{5}{6}$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{6}$ so $$u_n = \frac{5^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{6}$$

---

You can check it for $n=2$, where you have $4 \cdot 4$ possibilities for a tiling with two squares, and $5$ possibilities for a tiling with one block, so $u_2=21$. And $\frac{5^3 + (-1)^2}{6} = 21$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't understand the u0=1 and u1=4, where do you find this?

Comment: For $n=0$ there is only one possible tiling: do not put any block. Admittedly, you could not be convinced by this explanation and you are free to start at $n=1$ (and only compute by hand the first two values, for $1$ and $2$).
For $n=1$, you can only tile using one block, which can be four different colors, so you have four choices.
Let me know if that is not clear